# Issues with WiFi/Internet connection with Ubuntu 16.04 on a Mac

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, internet, macbook-pro

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on my Early-2011 MacBook Pro.

The wifi drivers seem to be installed fine but I keep experiencing issues. It's not that I don't have a connection. I do. But at times it gets interrupted, and after a while it returns back to normal. The thing is it happens so often, it's quite annoying (and it has nothing to do with my internet connection, it works fine).

Here are some details of my setup:

**lshw -C Network**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0f0
       version: 10
       serial: c8:2a:14:27:2a:5c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=57765-v1.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:a0400000-a040ffff memory:a0410000-a041ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 02
       serial: e4:ce:8f:0b:08:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.34 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:a0600000-a0603fff
```

**lspci -nn | grep 0280**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
```

**The "Additional Drivers" tab from Software and Update:**

[image]

---

Any idea what might be going on here or how I could solve it?